# asp.net core ef dbcontext in a class libary

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, n-tier-architecture

In my project I'm using 2 dbcontexts one is the default microsoft auth and the other is my own database context. I now have my asp project a logic class libary and a data class libary that contains my own DBContext with the datasets.

My question now is how could I do database querys without needing to pass the context from the asp core project to the data class libary.

so I can call the database in the logic class without needing a connection with the asp project. Sort of like the N tier architecture.

Thank you

further explanation
I have my GameContext data class libary

```
 public class GameContext : DbContext
{
    public GameContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options) { }

    public DbSet<Enemy> Enemies { get; set; }
    public DbSet<News> theNews { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Character> Characters { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Class> Classes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Inventory> Inventories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Models.Type> Types { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Inventory_has_Item> Inventory_has_Item { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Enemy_has_Item> Enemy_has_Item { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Equipment> Equipment { get; set; }    
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {            
        modelBuilder.Entity<Inventory_has_Item>()
            .HasKey(t => new { t.InventoryId, t.ItemId });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Enemy_has_Item>()
            .HasKey(t => new { t.EnemyId, t.ItemId });

    }        
}
```

from my logic class libary I want to do something like this

```
public async Task<List<GameData.Models.Enemy>> getAllEnemies()
    {


        GameData.Models.test test = new test(_context);


        List<GameData.Models.Enemy> enemies;


        enemies = await _context.Enemies.ToListAsync();
        return enemies;
    }
```

problem is that I now need to pass the _context from my asp mvc in the controllers to call a method in the logic libary like this

```
 public EnemiesController(GameContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        _enemies = new Enemies(_context);                        
    }
```

this works when doing things like index but when I do a create I get a dependency injecten error with the context

Comment: Can you add some pseudo code of what you want to do so that's clearer what you are asking? I am having a hard time understanding what you are trying to achieve. Also, is this ASP.NET 4 or ASP.NET Core? Also, "ASP" is another technology, please don't mix terms so much

Comment: thanks edited my question